# PyQt5 QTreeWidget disable on cell select style

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtreewidget

**File: preview_example.py**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'C:\Users\chris\My Projects\papinhio-player\ui/menu-1/playlists/preview/preview_example.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.7
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(1171, 1511)
        Dialog.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/rest-windows/assets/images/rest-windows/preview-sound-file.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        Dialog.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Dialog)
        self.gridLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(Dialog)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1169, 1509))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.gridLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.gridLayout_5.setObjectName("gridLayout_5")
        self.treeWidget = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.treeWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 400))
        self.treeWidget.setStyleSheet("QTreeWidget::item{\n"
"    height:60px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QTreeWidget::item:selected{\n"
"    background-color:#3399ff;\n"
"}")
        self.treeWidget.setAnimated(True)
        self.treeWidget.setObjectName("treeWidget")
        item_0 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget)
        item_0 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget)
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.treeWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.scrollArea, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Προεπισκόπηση λίστας αναπαραγωγής"))
        Dialog.setWhatsThis(_translate("Dialog", "Προεπισκόπηση αρχείου ήχου (για τοπική προβολή)"))
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(0, _translate("Dialog", "Α/Α"))
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(1, _translate("Dialog", "Τύπος"))
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(2, _translate("Dialog", "Τίτλος"))
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(3, _translate("Dialog", "Προεπισκόπιση"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.treeWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.treeWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(0, _translate("Dialog", "1"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(1, _translate("Dialog", "1"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(2, _translate("Dialog", "1"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(3, _translate("Dialog", "1"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(1).setText(0, _translate("Dialog", "2"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(1).setText(1, _translate("Dialog", "2"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(1).setText(2, _translate("Dialog", "2"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(1).setText(3, _translate("Dialog", "2"))
        self.treeWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In this QDialog a have a QTreeWidget.
I want when a row is selected the row to be blue with white text color (as it is) but i also **don't want the 'cell' of selected row to be highlighted special.**

Print screen:
[image]

In this example the third cell has wrong qss (because I clicked inside this cell) but the other has correct qss.

Possible solutions: QDelegate or QStyleItemOption or QBrush or QPallete..

Code snippet:

```py
class Delegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self,treeWidget):
        self.treeWidget = treeWidget
        super().__init__(treeWidget)
        
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):        

        if (
            index.row() == self.treeWidget.currentIndex().row() and
            index.column() == self.treeWidget.currentIndex().column()
        ):
            super().paint(painter, option, index)
            self.initStyleOption(option, index)
            painter.drawRect(option.rect)
            painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.white)
            painter.setBrush(QtGui.QColor("#3399ff"))
        else:
            super().paint(painter, option, index)
```

The above code fix a bit the problem but the solid black rectangle is still there...

Edit: This problem is well visibled in Fusion Style.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding the issue: are you talking about the slightly different background color? Also, the black rectangle you're mentioning is only visible in your delegate, and that's because *you* are painting it (the pen and brush is set afterwards, and is pointless); besides, if you want to have a different background color for an item, you should certainly not draw anything *after* calling `super().paint()`, since that would obviously paint *over* the item.

Answer (score 0):

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file '.\untitled.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.7
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(51, 153, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Highlight, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(51, 153, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Highlight, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 120, 215))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Highlight, brush)
        MainWindow.setPalette(palette)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.treeWidget = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.treeWidget.setObjectName("treeWidget")
        item_0 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget)
        item_0 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.treeWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)


        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.treeWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.treeWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(1).setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(1).setText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(1).setText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(1).setText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        self.treeWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)



class Style_tweaks(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):
    
    def drawPrimitive(self,element,option,painter,widget):
        if (element == QtWidgets.QStyle.PE_FrameFocusRect):
            return None
        QtWidgets.QProxyStyle.drawPrimitive(self,element, option, painter, widget)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.create("fusion"))
    proxy = Style_tweaks(app.style())
    app.setStyle(proxy)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see there is no style difference in cells. I am not pretty sure that's exactly the correct answer so feel free to comment.